# Inclusion-exclusion problem, k different balls into n different cells

Tags: combinatorics, inclusion-exclusion

I was given the following problem: in how many ways can one put $k$ different balls into $n$ different cells, such that $m$ cells remain empty? $m,n,k \ge1$ , $k \ge n-m$

I tried to solve it using Inclusion–exclusion principle. First, choose $m$ cells for the empty ones. Then, find in how many ways one can put $k$ different balls into $(n-m)$ different cells, such that no cell remains empty, then multiply the results. I got this answer:
$$\sum_{t=0}^{n-m} \frac{n!}{t! \cdot m!} \cdot(n-m-t)^{k-1} \cdot (-1)^t$$

Is my answer correct? Is it a good way to solve the problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Your approach seems correct. Make sure your calculation is correct.

Answer (score 0):

With this problem the salient feature is that the first guess which is

$$\sum_{q=m}^n {n\choose q} (-1)^{m-q} (n-q)^k$$

does not  produce the correct  answer. The underlying poset  has nodes
for  each subset  $P$  of the  set $Q$  of  $n$ cells  where the  node
represents cells from $P$  plus possibly additional cells being empty,
ordered by the superset relation with  the node of all cells $Q$ being
empty (which does not contain any configurations) being at the bottom.
(With  $P_1$ a  superset of  $P_2$  the configurations  of the  former
constitute  a subset  of the  latter.)  Now  a configuration  that has
exactly $p$ empty cells where $m\le p\le n$ receives total weight (sum
of the weights of all nodes where it is included)

$$\sum_{q=m}^p {p\choose q} (-1)^{m-q}.$$

While this yields  a weight of one  for $p=m$ it is not  equal to zero
for $p\gt  m$ and  hence cannot be  used to count  configurations with
exactly $m$ empty cells. A better  approach is to choose the $m$ empty
cells first  and use a poset  where the nodes $P$  represent the extra
empty cells in  addition to the $m$ already  selected, which no longer
participate in the inclusion-exclusion. This yields

$${n\choose m} \sum_{q=0}^{n-m} {n-m\choose q} (-1)^q
(n-m-q)^k.$$

Here we  are interested in  the count of  zero empty extra  cells. The
single node  with $q=n-m$  is at the  bottom.  With tbis  approach the
weight of  a configuration on  the remaining $n-m$ cells  with exactly
$p$ extra empty cells where $0\le p\le n-m$ is given by

$$\sum_{q=0}^{p} {p\choose q} (-1)^q.$$

This  evaluates to  one when  $p=0$ and  is zero  otherwise,  which is
precisely the weights  that we require for this  problem. Observe that
we have a Stirling number here which can be seen by writing

$$\frac{n!}{m!} \frac{1}{(n-m)!}
\sum_{q=0}^{n-m} {n-m\choose q} (-1)^{n-m-q} q^k$$

which yields

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
\frac{n!}{m!} {k\brace n-m}.}$$

If we had  not been asked to use  inclusion-exclusion the answer would
have been ${n\choose m} \times {k\brace n-m} (n-m)!$ by inspection.